# Listing server folders and sub folders using C# FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, streamreader, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to get full list of files, directories and sub-directories on tree view using `StreamReader`. The problem is it took too long and throws *"Operation time out exception" and shows only one level.

Here is my code

```
public void getServerSubfolder(TreeNode tv, string parentNode) {
  string ptNode;
  List<string> files = new List<string> ();
  try { 
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.
    Create(parentNode);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.userName, this.Password);
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.Timeout = 10000;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string fileList;
    string[] fileName;
    //MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd().ToString());
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
      fileList = reader.ReadLine();
      fileName = fileList.Split(' ');
      if (fileName[0] == "drwxr-xr-x") {
        // if it is directory
        TreeNode tnS = new TreeNode(fileName[fileName.Length - 1]);
        tv.Nodes.Add(tnS);
        ptNode = parentNode + "/" + fileName[fileName.Length - 1] + "/";
        getServerSubfolder(tnS, ptNode);
      } else files.Add(fileName[fileName.Length - 1]);
    }
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Sub--here " + ex.Message + "----" + ex.StackTrace);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it with different time out numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing similar things, but instead of using StreamReader.ReadLine() for each one, I get it all at once with StreamReader.ReadToEnd(). You don't need ReadLine() to just get a list of directories. Below is my entire code (Entire howto is explained in [this](http://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/how-to-create-an-ftp-client-in-c/) tutorial):

```
        FtpWebRequest request=(FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(path);
        request.Method=WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        List<ftpinfo> files=new List<ftpinfo>();

        //request.Proxy = System.Net.WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
        //request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password);
        Stream rs=(Stream)request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        OnStatusChange("CONNECTED: " + path, 0, 0);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs);
        string strList = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines=null;

        if (strList.Contains("\r\n"))
        {
            lines=strList.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"},StringSplitOptions.None);
        }
        else if (strList.Contains("\n"))
        {
            lines=strList.Split(new string[] {"\n"},StringSplitOptions.None);
        }

        //now decode this string array

        if (lines==null || lines.Length == 0)
            return null;

        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Length==0)
                continue;
            //parse line
            Match m= GetMatchingRegex(line);
            if (m==null) {
                //failed
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to parse line: " + line);
            }

            ftpinfo item=new ftpinfo();
            item.filename = m.Groups["name"].Value.Trim('\r');
            item.path = path;
            item.size = Convert.ToInt64(m.Groups["size"].Value);
            item.permission = m.Groups["permission"].Value;
            string _dir = m.Groups["dir"].Value;
            if(_dir.Length>0  && _dir != "-")
            {
                item.fileType = directoryEntryTypes.directory;
            } 
            else
            {
                item.fileType = directoryEntryTypes.file;
            }

            try
            {
                item.fileDateTime = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["timestamp"].Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                item.fileDateTime = DateTime.MinValue; //null;
            }

            files.Add(item);
        }

        return files;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great response. Worked when I read it once to the end. I din't have to use the whole code since I thought I have to include the library. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read (and cache) whole listing before recursing into subdirectories, otherwise the top-level request will timeout before you complete subdirectories listing.

You can keep using `ReadLine`, no need to use `ReadToEnd` and separate the lines yourself.

```
void ListFtpDirectory(
    string url, string rootPath, NetworkCredential credentials, List<string> list)
{
    FtpWebRequest listRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + rootPath);
    listRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    listRequest.Credentials = credentials;

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    using (FtpWebResponse listResponse = (FtpWebResponse)listRequest.GetResponse())
    using (Stream listStream = listResponse.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader listReader = new StreamReader(listStream))
    {
        while (!listReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            lines.Add(listReader.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] tokens =
            line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string name = tokens[8];
        string permissions = tokens[0];

        string filePath = rootPath + name;

        if (permissions[0] == 'd')
        {
            ListFtpDirectory(url, filePath + "/", credentials, list);
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Use the function like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "mypassword");
string url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/";
ListFtpDirectory(url, "", credentials, list);
```

---

A disadvantage of the above approach is that it has to parse server-specific listing to retrieve information about files and folders. The code above expects a common *nix-style listing. But many servers use a different format.

The `FtpWebRequest` unfortunately does not support the `MLSD` command, which is the only portable way to retrieve directory listing with file attributes in FTP protocol.

---

If you want to avoid troubles with parsing the server-specific directory listing formats, use a 3rd party library that supports the `MLSD` command and/or parsing various `LIST` listing formats; and recursive downloads.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can list whole directory with a single call to the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles):

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // List files
    IEnumerable<string> list =
        session.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/", null, EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories).
        Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.FullName);
}
```

Internally, WinSCP uses the `MLSD` command, if supported by the server. If not, it uses the `LIST` command and supports dozens of different listing formats.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*